# Is there a way to use NSIS to install an app in Win10 that can read C:\Windows?

Tags: windows-10, nsis, elevated-privileges, compatibility-mode

We have an application with a large installed base.  Long story short, for a limited time some new Win10 systems need to store their data as the Win7 systems do -- in C:\windows (this is non-negotiable, and temporary -- I know this is poor form, but it is a temporary workaround).

In order to do that, I assume we need to either have NSIS set compatibility mode, or set elevated user privileges.  But I'm open to other alternatives.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was also wrong in Windows 7 and every other Windows version released in the last 25 years.

While it would be possible to give all users write access to %windir%, it is a huge security issue and not something I can recommend.

Your best option is to modify your application so that it [requests UAC elevation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb756929(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in its [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests). If the application does not already have a embedded manifest (not requesting ComCtl32 v6 etc.) then you can theoretically use a [external .manifest file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2009/12/09/answers-to-several-application-manifest-mysteries-and-questions.aspx).

A less ideal solution is to set the compatibility flag:

```
!include x64.nsh

${If} ${IsWow64}
SetRegView 64
${EndIf} 
WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" "$InstDir\MyApp.exe" "RUNASADMIN" 
SetRegView Default
```

[Application compatibility layers are there for the customer, not for the program](https://web.archive.org/web/20100717010649if_/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/11/9976571.aspx) but I suppose we are way past trying to follow the Microsoft guidelines.

Comment: This is a really temporary workaround; we're moving from writing config to INI files to putting it into an encrypted XML file, but the software to edit the XML files isn't ready yet; so we just need something to make do for a month or so.  This will do nicely!  Thanks!